# Static constructors and field initialization order in C#

Tags: c#, static, static-initialization

This sample from C# in a Nutshell says it writes 0 followed by 3 due to "the field initializer that instantiates a Foo executes before X is initialized to 3".

```
class Program {
  static void Main() { Console.WriteLine (Foo.X); }   // 3
}

class Foo
{
    public static Foo Instance = new Foo(); //static field 1
    public static int X = 3; //static field 2
    
    Foo() => Console.WriteLine (X);   // 0
}
```

My question is, why does this not go into an infinite recursion due to static field 1 which makes a new Foo (which makes a new Foo, which makes a new Foo, etc.)?

Comment: static makes only one objecvt - shared between all instances of Foo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at what's going on. Before`Foo` class addressing `static` fields must be
initialized.

```
class Program {
  static void Main() { 
    // Before Foo class is addressed (here Foo.X), Foo must be initialized 
    Console.WriteLine(Foo.X); 
  }   
}
```

.Net will do it *in order they are mentioned* in the class declaration:

```
class Foo
{
    // Will be run first
    public static Foo Instance = new Foo(); 
    // Will be run second
    public static int X = 3; 
    
    Foo() => Console.WriteLine(X);   
}
```

1. So far so good, `Instance` start its initialization

```
public static Foo Instance = new Foo();
```

constructor `Foo()` called which prints `X`: `Foo() => Console.WriteLine (X);` note,
that since `X` has *not been initialized*, `0` will be printed.

2. `X` will be initialized, it's now `3`

Initialization is completed now, and .Net is ready to adddress `Foo` class

```
Console.WriteLine(Foo.X);
```

and `3` will be printed (note the 2nd step of the initialization)

Answer (score 1):

Static fields and properties are shared across all instances of a class, and get initialized in a special constructor called `.cctor` that gets called when the class is first referenced.

So the compiled code is something similar to

```
class Foo
{
    public static Foo Instance;
    public static int X;
    .cctor() {
        Instance = new Foo();
        X = 3;
    }
    
    Foo() => Console.WriteLine (X);
}
```

The call flow would be `Foo::.cctor` -> `Foo::Foo()` -> `Foo:get_X()`.

So there is no recursion, but `X` will have its default value when `.cctor` is called.